# How to store results of an API call that creates records with python into pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, api

I am trying to create a new customer in my billing systems and then receive a response back because I need the newly created customer id in pandas df

This is what I have so far - when the results are returned - they will return the same JSON + there will be a customer id and created time stamp - and I need to store all those results into a pandas df to work with further. This is what I have below - from my understanding - I need to append the df - but all examples I've seen so far work with 1 value - how do I do it with multiple values?

```
new_customers = pd.DataFrame()
for customer,r in sh2_ws_df.iterrows():
    cb.Customer.create({
        "first_name": r['Billing First Name'],
        "last_name": r['Billing Last Name'],
        "email": r['Billing Email'],
        "phone": r['Billing Phone'],
        "company": r['Account Name'],
        "auto_collection": "on",
        "net_term_days": 0,
        "allow_direct_debit": 'true',
        "taxability": "taxable",
        "locale": "en",
        "cf_referral_partner": r['cb_referral_partner'],
        "cf_business_type": r['cf_business_type'],
        "billing_address" : {
            "first_name" : r['Billing First Name'],
            "last_name" : r['Billing Last Name'],
            "email": r['Billing Email'],
            "company": r['Account Name'],
            "phone": r['Billing Phone'],
            "line1" : r['Billing Address 1'],
            "line2": r['Billing Address 2'],
            "city" : r['Billing City'],
            "state" : r['Billing State'],
            "zip" : r['Billing Zip'],
            "country" : r['Billing Country']
        }
}
    new_customers.append()
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), `append` is deprecated so better use `concat`.

```
new_customers = pd.DataFrame()
for customer,r in sh2_ws_df.iterrows():
    # I assume that a DataFrame cust is returned
    cust = cb.Customer.create({
        "first_name": r['Billing First Name'],
        "last_name": r['Billing Last Name'],
        "email": r['Billing Email'],
        "phone": r['Billing Phone'],
        "company": r['Account Name'],
        "auto_collection": "on",
        "net_term_days": 0,
        "allow_direct_debit": 'true',
        "taxability": "taxable",
        "locale": "en",
        "cf_referral_partner": r['cb_referral_partner'],
        "cf_business_type": r['cf_business_type'],
        "billing_address" : {
            "first_name" : r['Billing First Name'],
            "last_name" : r['Billing Last Name'],
            "email": r['Billing Email'],
            "company": r['Account Name'],
            "phone": r['Billing Phone'],
            "line1" : r['Billing Address 1'],
            "line2": r['Billing Address 2'],
            "city" : r['Billing City'],
            "state" : r['Billing State'],
            "zip" : r['Billing Zip'],
            "country" : r['Billing Country']
        }
    }
    # at the end of the for loop, concatenate the new customer 'cust' with the new_customers DataFrame
    new_customers = pd.concat([new_customers, cust], ignore_index=True)
```

**Note:** Couldn't see which variable was storing the data for the new customer so I added the variable `cust`. Adapt yourself accordingly.

Comment: good to know it worked for you